# How can I programmatically add a Control to a Windows UWP UserControl?

Tags: c#, uwp

Let's assume that I have an empty Windows UWP UserControl, i.e. a class deriving from `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.UserControl` and that this UserControl is defined in C# code only, i.e. no XAML is involved. How can I programmatically add additional controls, such as `Button` to this UserControl?

There is no collection of child controls that I can add the button to and I just cannot figure out how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: You set the Content property to another XAML control. Remember this can only be a single element, so if you need a list of children, you'll need to use a List or Grid.

Comment: Indeed, the `Content` property is what I was looking for. Thanks for the hint with the List/Grid. Would you mind posting your comment as an answer so that I can mark it accordingly?

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the `Content` property to another XAML control. Remember this can only be a single element, so if you need a list of children, you'll need to use a `List` or `Grid`.